# How to iterate through a list of dictionaries?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

Hello guys I have a dictionary,a key value pair , which the value has a list of dictionaries:

```
tables = {
    "aaa.acs": [
        {"2021-02-04 02:06:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:07:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:08:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:09:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:10:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:11:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:12:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:13:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:14:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:15:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:16:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:17:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:18:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:19:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:20:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:21:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:22:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:23:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:24:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:25:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:26:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:27:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:28:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:29:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:30:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:31:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:32:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:33:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:34:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:35:00-05:00": 0},
    ],
    "accss.msft": [
        {"2021-02-04 02:06:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:07:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:08:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:09:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:10:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:11:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:12:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:13:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:14:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:15:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:16:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:17:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:18:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:19:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:20:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:21:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:22:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:23:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:24:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:25:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:26:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:27:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:28:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:29:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:30:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:31:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:32:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:33:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:34:00-05:00": 0},
        {"2021-02-04 02:35:00-05:00": 0},
    ],
}
```

I have tried this method  of obtaining it but I am not satisfied  with this performance  :

```
for test in tables.values():
    for value in test:
        for time, cost in value.items():
            print(time, cost)
```

How can I access the key /value pair of this list of dictionaries? I am considering if it's possible to convert this from list to dict for better performance. What do you guys think of ways I can implement this logic?

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import chain

for your_dict in chain(*tables.values()):
    key, value = tuple(*your_dict.items())
    print(key, value)
```

`*tables .values()` will unpack all the list into a single iterable which will give dictionary when iterated upon.
`tuple(*your_dict.items())` this will unpack the key value pairs into a tuple